# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while creating persistent znodes?

Tags: flags, apache-zookeeper

After I have started the Zookeeper server from windows command prompt and also started the zkConsole.. I tried creating the znode persistent node as `/be` from the command prompt like this -

```
WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] create -s /be
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processZKCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:700)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.processCmd(ZooKeeperMain.java:593)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.executeLine(ZooKeeperMain.java:365)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.run(ZooKeeperMain.java:323)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain.main(ZooKeeperMain.java:282)
```

And as soon as I did that, I got an exception on the console as mentioned above.. As this is my first time so I am not sure how to resolve this issue? Any pointers will be appreciated on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you are using 3.4 version of Zookeeper. There is a JIRA Issue `ZOOKEEPER-780` that talks about the same thing.. It should be fixed in the later version.

But for now you can pass empty data while creating znodes like this -

```
create -s /be ""
```